# Resolving a singleton error in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, firebird, firebird-psql

I have the following stored procedure in Firebird SQL:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_REPORT_USD
(
  PER SMALLINT
)
RETURNS
(
  ACCOUNT_NUMBER CHAR(21),
  AMOUNT NUMERIC(15, 4)
  )

AS

BEGIN

SELECT
      L.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, SUM(CURRROUND(L.DEBIT,2)-CURRROUND(L.CREDIT,2))
   FROM
      LEDGER L
   WHERE
      L.LEDGER_ACCOUNT = '31621' AND L.PERIOD = :PER
   GROUP BY
      L.ACCOUNT_NUMBER

   INTO
      ACCOUNT_NUMBER, AMOUNT;

SUSPEND;

END
```

When I run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM SP_REPORT_USD('17')
```

I get the following error:

> MULTIPLE ROWS IN SINGLETON SELECT
>   AT PROCEDURE 'SP_REPORT_USD' LINE: 15, COL: 1

Line 15 Col 1 is where my select statement starts when doing the stored procedure.

I did test the following query:

```
SELECT
   L.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, INV.DESCRIPTION, SUM(-(CURRROUND(L.DEBIT,2) - CURRROUND(L.CREDIT,2)))
FROM
   LEDGER L join INVENTORY INV ON L.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = INV.STOCK_CODE
WHERE
   L.LEDGER_ACCOUNT = '31621' AND L.PERIOD = 17
GROUP BY
   L.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, INV.DESCRIPTION
```

And the results where as expected. So I know my query logic is correct, I am just doing something wrong with the stored procedure.

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: How many rows do you expect this procedure to produce: a single row or possibly more than one row? Please provide sample data and expected output for that sample data.

Comment: Yes, I am expecting the result two be two columns with multiple rows

Comment: @WimHollebrandse This is Firebird, and those are required.

Comment: are you coming from MS SQL background? In Firebird making such an SP is usually bad idea. Better make a `VIEW`. Surely, in a View you can not pass parameters, but you might use usual `WHERE`

Comment: I am not coming from any SQL background, I am learning on the go here. If you don't mind me asking, why is this SP a bad idea?

Comment: Because it hides "implementation detail", it is a black box. It can not use indexes, for example, because it does not know where the data, ejected by SP, was taken from. Make & fill two tables both with PK, then do `select * from t1,t2 where t1.id=t2.id` - and check the `query plan`.  You would see indexes used to match rows. Now wrap both tables into such SPs and join SPs - now you would have much slower `natural scan` on BOTH. n*m scaling instead of linear. Also read Firebird FAQ about joining of tables with SP, there are some gotchas, reasonable retroactively, but u better read in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that inside a stored procedure, a `SELECT` statement is for selecting values from a single row only (a so-called singleton select). Your query is producing multiple rows, hence the error *"multiple rows in singleton select"*.

If you want to produce multiple rows, you need to use the [`FOR SELECT`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql-forselect) statement, and the `SUSPEND` statement must be in the body of this `FOR SELECT` statement:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_REPORT_USD(PER SMALLINT)
  RETURNS (ACCOUNT_NUMBER CHAR(21), AMOUNT NUMERIC(15, 4))
AS
BEGIN
   FOR 
     SELECT L.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, SUM(CURRROUND(L.DEBIT,2)-CURRROUND(L.CREDIT,2))
     FROM LEDGER L
     WHERE L.LEDGER_ACCOUNT = '31621' AND L.PERIOD = :PER
     GROUP BY L.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
     INTO :ACCOUNT_NUMBER, :AMOUNT 
   DO
   BEGIN
     SUSPEND;
   END
END
```

The `BEGIN`...`END` around the `SUSPEND;` is optional in this case (as it is a single statement), but I prefer to include them always.